# Driver Expression: Bind "Visibility in Viewport" to self.parent > hide_render?

Tags: scripting, drivers

I need to setup a driver to bind the "Visibility in Viewport" property of on object to its parent "hide_render" property.

I want to use an expression only. So I did lots of research and with my understanding the following expression should work, but it does not:

```
self.parent.hide_render
```

What am I doing wrong? Or am I missing something important?

self.hide_render works. So the prerequisites seem to be met (e.g. Enabling "Auto Run Python Script" and checkbox "Use Self")

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can access to direct properties here. Even if I tried python drivers:

```
import bpy

def parent_hidden(this):
    return this.parent.hide_render

bpy.app.driver_namespace["parent_hidden"] = parent_hidden
```

it didn't work correctly because Blender don't know then to update driver. So the only way to do this is that:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So you are saying that it is not possible with a simple expression?
Using Input Value works, but it always needs an absolute reference to a specific object. So I am looking for a expression solution...

Comment: You can use python driver, but it doesn't work properly